# Excel VB code to handle an array that has commas in the filenames

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that reads cells that contain a comma seperated list of filenames and converts the values of these cells to an array.  This VB array is then used to verfiy the existence of the files listed in another worksheet.

I have an issue with filesnames listed in single cell that have commas in some of the filenames:

```
 Cell A1: testfile.txt, testfile2.txt, testfile3.pdf, test, file, 4.doc.
 Cell A2:testfile5.txt, testfile6.text
```

When my VB code reads the above cells in Cell A1 -  test, file and 4.doc are being split into separate array values. I know using comma's in a filename is not good practice but unfortunately I have no control over that.

Does anyone have a nice method of reading the cell values correctly into an array so that in the above example test, file, 4.doc is recorded as one value in the array.. not 3??

Currently the part of my code in question is:

```
MySearchString = Worksheets("Comms Summary").Range("G" & RowCounter).text 
'read string from cell to be converted to array
FileListArray() = Split(MySearchString, ", ") 
'split string into array
R = UBound(FileListArray) 
' resize array.
```

Comment: How do you know that there _aren't_ three files called `test` `file` and `4.doc.` ?  For that matter, how do you know there isn't a file called `testfile.txt, testfile2.txt` ?

Comment: I can definitely confirm from browsing to the actual files on the server that files with comma's in their name do exist. Typically users are naming files like "CWS, BTB, agreement.pdf"  I have asked the users not to include comma's in the name but unfortunately they continue to do so. I can find thousands of files that are named this way in the directories I search.

Comment: Not really my point.  For your code to correctly dissect the file name list, it needs to be able to distinguish commas in the names from list separators. What distinguishing features of the file names can it use to do that?  If the names are created by other people then there may be none.

Comment: Yeah there are no distinguishing features unfortunately. What I really need is a function that reads the array, finds any array values that do not include a file extention i.e are missing "." in the file name, keep a count of the array location and combine these array values into a single array value. So for example Array(x) - test, Array(x+1) - file and Array(x+2) - 4.doc are combined into a new Array(x+3) and  arrays values x,x+1,x+2 are deleted from the array.  I am working on this now with instr functions looping through the array etc.. but I was hoping someone may have done this before.

Comment: I think that using Split will be counter productive here.  You could try a RegEx to identify names ending with an extension.  Even that will be risky as file names can contains 0 or more `.`'s.  An alternative but more complex approach might be to try each possible breakup of the comma separated string, reducing the string each time a match is found.

Answer (score 1):

This looks impossible for me, because someone could name his file

`document.txt, something.doc` (yes this is **one** file looking like two!).

Even if this makes absolutely no sense, this is considered as a **valid** file name and you will be unable to detect these. You can't build a secure function to filter that.

The only approach I could imagine is to loop your array and check for every item if the file exists in your file system. But if it doesn't exist you will have to implement a very smart logic to find the true file name. This all doesn't look like a clean implementation to me.

I would approach from another side: How is the comma separated file list generated? Can you generate it as semicolon separated file list? Your problem is definitely the comma separated list. Try to fix it. Commas are a really bad separator for files.

Comment: Yes I think your right. The comma seperated list is created from an export from another software package that I don't have control over. However this software does allow you to create a calculated field that supports C# functions. I am considering perhaps trying a C# function to try and change the delimiter between the file names to something like a semi colon before the data is exported and imported into excel.